# How to use jQuery dataTable to sort dateTime format 01-JAN-2016 10:00

Tags: jquery, datatables

I code for a search result table, and I get the `startDate`, `startTime`, `endDate`, and `endTime` from *oracle database*; and use ajax to show the data in front-end, we use Firefox for all of the development and test.

I need to sort based on the `startDate` and `startTime` (some data does not have `startTime`), also `endDate` and `endTime` (some data does not have `endTime`) when I click the sort icon. I use **moment.js**, but failed. Could you help me. this is my js side code.

```
searchRequest =
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: G_REL_URL + '/getData',
        data: inputs,
        async: true,
        error: function (objAJAXRequest, strError) {
            try {
                console.log('AJAX error: ' + strError);
            } catch (e) {
            }
        },
        dataType: 'HTML',
        complete: function (response, status) {
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $('#div_search_bottom_srch').html(data).show();
            $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm');
            $('#search_results_table').dataTable({
                "aaSorting": [],
                "sScrollY": "400px",
                "asStripeClasses": [],
                "bFilter": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "scrollX": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "type": "datetime-moment", targets: [3, 4] },
                    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0, 6, 7, 8, 9] }
                ]

            });
```

It seems it only sort based the date, and ignore month and year.

Comment: How exactly `moment.js` failed?

Comment: Please look at my attached image,it shows the details.

Comment: Please see my image attachment, it shows the detail.